# Pentaho (PDI) Dynamic Authorization Key for Rest Client

Tags: json, api, pentaho, rest-client, pentaho-data-integration

I'm creating a transformation using Pentaho (PDI). I have an API that I'm trying to hit and pull back data but the problem is that the authorization token that I have to pass in/use to my Rest Client step is dynamic. I.e., I have to make a HTTP Post call to create a new token and then use that new token each time I want to do a "Get" call within my Rest Client step. I have no problem doing the HTTP post and getting the authorization key each time. Currently I am outputting that key to a json file but I can put it in a database or wherever is needed, if needed.

**My question is:** how do I pass this dynamic authorization key to my Rest Client step? Generally, a Rest Client step has to have a "Generate Rows" step before it, but I can't seem to pass a dynamic value to the "Generate Rows" step. If I could my problem would be solved. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to pass this key through as a variable, using the Set Variables step in the transformation that has the HTTP POST, and capture it with the Get Variables Step in a following Transformation.